# Why didn't Glory simply "taste" all of the Scoobies?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

So Glory tastes Tara's blood and says Tara isn't the key.

Why didn't Glory et al get blood samples as soon as they discovered the key is human/vampire/one of the Scooby Gang?

Comment: When I think of Her Glorificus, the words 'sensible' and 'methodical' don't *immediately* spring to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it was Ben who kept her from hurting or killing all the Scoobies. So even if she thought of 'tasting' all of their blood individually, Ben (who knows that Dawn is The Key). prevents Glory from doing it.

She even says it herself that Ben is the little part of humanity inside her that keeps her from acting sometimes.

> **Glory:** *Don't be so hard on the boy. He just wants to live. Most guys would do the same. Besides, **he's probably the reason your sis and her little cartoon pals are still alive. That little nagging pinch of humanity that makes me go for the hurt instead of the kill**. Lowering myself to trade blows with the Slayer when I should have just put my fist through her heart. It's gotta be Ben.*
>
> <sub><sup>BtVS: The Weight of the World</sup></sub>

Comment: This is probably correct, but could benefit from some evidence (transcripts, etc.) to back it up.

Comment: How is that? I've added the actual quote from the script.

Comment: Much better. Now worthy of an upvote.

Comment: no idea why i have no comment or accept here even though i upvoted. thanks!